# What are the deficiences of the sampling frame?

Tags: probability, sampling

A directory of the city, four years ago, enlists directions in order along every street, and gives the names of people living in each direction. For a survey conducted annually by an interview with the townsfolk, What are the deficiences of the sampling frame? By using the directory, you would choose a list of addresses  or a list of people? Why?

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple question - do you think a four-year-old list of addresses, or a four-year-old list of residents, is more likely to still be accurate now? Which one is more likely to change? Also, if you chose, for example, the list of people, how would you contact them?